# How do I extract the names of IronPython script arguments in C#

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I have a Python script as follows:

```
def VSH(GR, GRsand, GRshale): 
    '''Calculates Vsh from gamma inputs'''
    value = (((GR-GRsand)/(GRshale-GRsand)))
    if (value > 100.0):
      value = 100.0
    elif (value < 0.0):
        value = 0.0
    return value
```

From C# I have a loop that in IronPython 2.2 would extract the 3 arguments.

```
foreach (string variableName in (PythonTuple)inputFunction.func_code.co_varnames)
{
    // do something here
}
```

Now in IronPython 2.7.5 I get the names of the 4 variables, which makes sense, but breaks the old code. From the watch I get:

```
co_varnames tuple, 4 items  IronPython.Runtime.PythonTuple
[0] "GR"    object {string}
[1] "GRsand"    object {string}
[2] "GRshale"   object {string}
[3] "value" object {string}
```

Looking at the object inputFunction.func_code in the debugger, I don't see anything that would return just the arguments. I do see the property co_argcount = 3. If I could be sure that the arguments were always first in the list of variables, then I could use it to filter out the local variables. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
// using System.Reflection;
dynamic func = scope.GetVariable("VSH");
var code = func.__code__;
var argNamesProperty = code.GetType().GetProperty("ArgNames", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
string[] argNames = (string[])argNamesProperty.GetValue(code, null);
// argNames = ["GR", "GRsand", "GRshale"]
```

You were looking in the right place, but unfortunately the `IronPython.Runtime.FunctionCode.ArgNames` property is private. With reflection, we can ignore that and just get the argument names anyway.

Here's my complete test setup:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
    ObjectOperations ops = engine.CreateOperations();
    ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(@"
def VSH(GR, GRsand, GRshale): 
    '''Calculates Vsh from gamma inputs'''
    value = (((GR-GRsand)/(GRshale-GRsand)))
    if (value > 100.0):
        value = 100.0
    elif (value < 0.0):
        value = 0.0
    return value");
    CompiledCode compiled = source.Compile();
    compiled.Execute(scope);

    dynamic func = scope.GetVariable("VSH");
    var code = func.__code__;
    var argNamesProperty = code.GetType().GetProperty("ArgNames", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    string[] argNames = (string[])argNamesProperty.GetValue(code, null);
    // argNames = ["GR", "GRsand", "GRshale"]
}
```

I'm sure that you can trim down everything before the `dynamic func = ...` line, because you probably have access to your `VSH` function already.

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfectly. I will have to remember that trick to get the private property.